# Reliable actor reentrancy across different actor types

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

From reading [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-reentrancy/) I see that actors are re-entrant, and I would expect the following to be true:  if I have a single type of actor `ThespianType` but three specific actors of `ThespianType` (`T1`, `T2`, and `T3`), then this won't deadlock:

`(external client) -> T1.MethodA() -> T2.MethodB() -> T3.MethodC() -> T1.MethodD()`

My question is: does the same reentrancy extend to multiple actor types?

For example, say we have:

- two Actor types `PainterType` and `BrushType`; and
- one actor of each type: painter `P1` and brush `B2`

Now this happens:

`(external client) -> P1.MethodX() -> B2.MethodY() -> P1.MethodZ()`

Assume that `MethodZ()` is a simple method with no blocking calls.

Question: will this deadlock (or throw a ServiceFabric exception due to detected deadlock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deadlock should happen as long as you use Actors correctly (not starting your own threads for instance). The type doesn't matter.

> The Actors runtime allows reentrancy by default. This means that if an
>   actor method of Actor A calls a method on Actor B, which in turn calls
>   another method on Actor A, that method is allowed to run. This is
>   because it is part of the same logical call-chain context. All timer
>   and reminder calls start with the new logical call context. See the
>   Reliable Actors reentrancy for more details.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/